# How to select the second row in a table without where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Need to select the second row in SQL Server 2008 R2 without where clause

Comment: By using offset we can done in sql server 2012 but am using sql server 2008R2 so i need an alternate of offset fetch next

Answer (score 5):

There is no "second row" in a table, because tables represent *unordered* sets.  You can have a second row based on some ordering however.  So let me assume you have an ordering column.

Then, you can use nested queries and `top`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from (select top (2) t.*
      from t
      order by ordering_col asc
     ) t
order by ordering_col desc;
```